# Switching from one view to another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

First of all I have to state that I am a complet newbeginner at Objective-C and iOS-programming.

Okey, so I have a simple app running, but I am facing some problems trying to switch fron one view to another. The plan is to do the "login-logic" in the view called `RootView` and then send the user to the `DataViewController` afterwards. I've tried googeling around, but no matter how I try to implement the code, it makes Xcode cry.

How can I achive the wanted effect?

Here are the following files:

**RootViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@end
```

**RootViewController.m**

```
@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

@end
```

**DataViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DataViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dataLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
@end
```

**DataViewController.m**

```
#import "DataViewController.h"

@interface DataViewController ()

@end

@implementation DataViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

@end
```

It is pretty much just an empty template, but for some reason it does not work with the solutions I've tried earier.

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: I suggest you read the 2 documents linked at the top of the UIViewController class reference. They will explain a lot, and you will be very frustrated if you don't learn the basics before trying to write apps.

Comment: @rdelmar: I guess you are right, but I have 10 years of experience behind me. I learn best when I have some sort of project to keep me going. I usually manage to google the right solutions, but not this time ;)

Comment: I think googling is a very bad way to start out with iOS -- it, and this site are good for answering specific questions, but to understand Apple's paradigm for programming in iOS, and particularly for learning about view controllers, the heart of iOS, you'll get a much more coherent and complete understanding from the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work with this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    UIViewController *mtvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GeoPartyDataViewController"];
    [self presentViewController: mtvc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are ready to move on, in your `RootViewController` (can be in any method you like):

```
GeoPartyDataViewController *dataController = [[GeoPartyDataViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeoPartyDataViewController.xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dataController animated:TRUE];
```

Don't forget to have `#import "DataViewController.h"` in your `RootViewController.m`.

An assumption made base on the info you gave so far, your `DataViewController` has an associated `.xib` file named `GeoPartyDataViewController.xib`. This is just one example. If you are working with storyboards, or some other mechanism, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hey, thanks for great answer. I forgot to mention that I am using storyboards. Your code does not do anything, but (for som reason) does not make the app crash.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `GeoPartyDataViewController.h`  to `RootViewController.m` such like

```
#import "GeoPartyDataViewController.h"
```

And now for go to `GeoPartyDataViewController`, you need to create  instance of it .

```
GeoPartyDataViewController *obj =[[GeoPartyDataViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeoPartyDataViewController.xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentViewController:obj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Above code write in relavent place that you want to go on `GeoPartyDataViewController`.